# Why do successive istream_iter objects increment the iterated stream?

Tags: c++, stringstream, istream-iterator

Why does the following code output `c`?

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::string p( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" );
  std::stringstream ss(p);
  std::istream_iterator<char> i( ss );
  std::istream_iterator<char> j( ss );
  std::istream_iterator<char> k( ss );
  std::cout << *k << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ -g ./main.cpp && ./a.out
c
```

It's sort of like each successive `istream_iterator` instance is implicitly iterating "something internal" to the `stringstream`. Why doesn't each `istream_iterator` instance start at the start of its `istream_type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [constructor of `istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator) performs reading, and `i`, `j`, `k` use the same stream so they're interactive.

(emphasis mine)

> 3) Initializes the iterator, stores the address of stream in a data
>   member, and **performs the first read from the input stream to
>   initialize the cached value data member**.

Comment: Oh...and reading from the stream automatically "increments" to the next "element" in the stream, correct?

Comment: @StoneThrow Yes, so if you perform reading again you'll get the next value, which is expected behavior. And `i`, `j`, `k` use the same stream so they're interactive.