# Is there a istream const iterator?

Tags: c++, istream, const-iterator, istream-iterator

Is there such a thing as a std::istream const iterator?

The following code won't compile because the `std::istream_iterator` in `foo()` can't bind to the `const std::istream` reference to the temporary object created in `main()`.

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

void foo( const std::istream& s )
{
  std::istream_iterator<char> i( s );
  // No std::istream_const_iterator, but anything by another name?
  std::cout << *i;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::string p( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" );
  foo( std::stringstream(p) );

  return 0;
}
```

Is there a `istream` iterator that can bind to a const `istream`?

Having just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61356433/why-do-successive-istream-iter-objects-increment-the-iterated-stream/61356471?noredirect=1#comment108542692_61356471), I just learned that `istream_iterator` ctors initialize and *perform the first read*. I guess I'm still not clear: does that read necessarily modify the bound `istream`? If not, it seems like there ought to be some kind of const iterator that can bind to a const `istream`, no?

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ -g ./main.cpp && ./a.out
./main.cpp: In function ‘void foo(const istream&)’:
./main.cpp:84:34: error: binding reference of type ‘std::istream_iterator<char>::istream_type&’ {aka ‘std::basic_istream<char>&’} to ‘const istream’ {aka ‘const std::basic_istream<char>’} discards qualifiers
   84 |   std::istream_iterator<char> i( s );
      |                                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iterator:66,
                 from ./main.cpp:80:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stream_iterator.h:68:38: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_iterator(std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_type&) [with _Tp = char; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Dist = long int; std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>::istream_type = std::ba
sic_istream<char>]’
   68 |       istream_iterator(istream_type& __s)
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Comment: What would you do with a stream that's const? You'd never be able to read from it.

Comment: @cigien - that's the crux of my question: does reading a stream modify the stream, or just the binding object, e.g. the istream_iterator? Compile error implies the former, but I'm trying to learn/understand if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, the stream gets modified when you read from it. It's basically an input iterator.

Comment: The short answer is that, yes, reading from a stream modifies its state.   Over-simplistically, a stream keeps track of position within some sequence of data and reading from the steam shifts the position - represented by the stream iterator.   Otherwise, only one thing could ever be read from the stream.  What you probably need to do is change `foo()` to accept a `std:string`, create the stream using the passed string (e.g. like you are doing in `main()`, but use a named variable), and read from the stream as needed.  The stream will cease to exist when the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does that read necessarily modify the bound `istream`?

Yes.

`istream_iterator` is a convenience class that allows one to treat `istream` objects as though they are containers such as a `std::vector` or an array.

Underneath, the `istream` is the object used to read from the stream. And yes, reading from a stream does modify an `istream`. How else would the `istream` keep track of internal state to indicate whether the attempt to read was successful or not, how many characters were read, etc.?

Since you need a non-`const istream` objects to read, it make no sense to be able to construct a `istream_iterator` from `const istream` objects.

Comment: Got it. I didn't know either way until your answer, but I guessed that maybe the binding iterator held metadata about the state of file reads - obviously incorrect. Thanks for enlightening.

Comment: @StoneThrow, you're welcome. Glad I was able to help.